# Filter everything but letters and "-"

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to write a function that filteres everything from an input to only letters and the symbol "-". I want that symbol since the input contains names, and someone may be called Jean-Paul, this is my current code:

```
if(!preg_match('/^\[a-zA-Z]+$/',$string)) {
 // Containing something other than a-z and A-Z
}
```

`$string = 'Jean-Paul';` now gives that the string contains illegal characters, but how can I do so that it accepts "`-`" ?

Comment: Nothing that reading about regular expressions in about 2 minutes wouldn't have solved

Comment: Sorry for not being as smart as you, Alexander

Comment: I'm sorry you think this is about being smart or not

Comment: You're right, Alexander. I should have tried by myself harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by **"filter"** you mean delete unwanted characters, then use

```
$s = preg_replace("/[^a-z-]/i", "", $s);
```

or

```
$s = preg_replace("/[^a-z-]/i", "", iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $s));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if (!preg_match('/^[A-Z-]+$/i', $string)) {
 // Contains something other than A-Z (case-insensitive) or -
}
```

A `-` is treated as a literal dash inside a character class if it's the first or last character there.

Be aware that `"Jean-Rémy"` will still fail. Are you sure you want to restrict yourself to ASCII letters?

Comment: Unless you add something like `$string = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $string);` to help avoid fails.